# update item in sharepoint List A depending on a result in List B

Tags: sharepoint, powerapps, power-automate

So I have 2 lists

1st list contains Materials, and each material got its own unique number (doesn't equal ID No. given by SP) and the Quantity of the material on hand.

The 2nd list contains a lookup column for the unique material number, and the user will type how much he/she withdraw from the material, just like a log.

So after a couple of hours searching, I could finally build a flow that will automatically calculate the difference between the Qty. On hand and the withdrawn Qty. using

```
triggerBody()?['Search_x0020_for_x0020_Q_x002e_C1']?['Value']
```

to "copy" the value of the lookup column as a number to another column in the same list so I can calculate the difference.

**NOW I need to update the Qty. in the 1st list!**

So I need a flow that will lookup for the unique material number and updates the material number.

at the same time, I'm afraid if it gets updated through this flow it'll be updated in the 2nd list which will create an infinite loop,
because I've tried to create a flow that will update the amount and it resulted with a loop :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using a new field as a flag to determine whether the update is made from the flow or not. Call the update action only if the update is not by a flow.

Approach 1: You can create the a new field called 'FlowUpdateTime' update the field and 'Last Modified  Date' field whenever you update List using flow.Then compare both before any update to understand whether the update is made by the flow or not.

You can either use this approach or any other approach

Comment: Thanks, That solves the loop.
But what about updating the older fields?!

Comment: Could you please elaborate what you meant by older fields

Comment: Older fields in the SP list that already been added as seen in this picture https://imgur.com/a/0ZG2TYP

Comment: There will be no impact as FlowUpdateTime is empty for older items

Comment: But older fields does get updated as you see in the previous comment :\